# Use pandas crosstab + columns aggregation on multiple colmuns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have the initial table below:

[image: initial table]

And I want to achieve this format:

[image: final format]

I managed to get the requested shape for one "val" at once. But it's not very useful in my case, as every table contains many values and the final result should be 1 consolidated table:

```
d={"name":["A","B","C","A","B","C"],"category":["1","1","1","2","2","2"],"val1":[5.5,2.3,4.2,3.5,3,3.7],"val2":[2.2,2.2,2.2,1.1,1.1,1.1
],"val3":[7.1,6.2,7.4,0.2,4,6.2]}

df=pd.DataFrame(d)
pd.crosstab(index=df["name"],columns=df["category"],values=df["val1"],aggfunc="mean",colnames=["val1"])
```

`

Comment: Small advice: Do not use keywords, `dict` in this case, as variable.

Comment: `df.pivot(index='name', columns='category')`, or `pivot_table` if you have duplicates and want to aggregate